# Bootstrap modal window not being correctly displayed and not behaving correctly in ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

From a view (let's say MyView.cshtml) in ASP.NET MVC application I am displaying a modal window, _MyConfirmModalWnd.cshtml. I have placed the modal window in Views\Shared folder.

Modal window is shown but some things are not working well:

- Look and feel is not being show correctly
- Cross button is not being correctly placed in the window
- When I click on cross button it is not working, modal window is not closed.
- Modal window is not being vertically and horizontally centered on the screen despite I am indicating using modal-dialog-centered class.

My modal window is shown as below:

[image]

instead of being shown with a look and feel similar to that shown in bootstrap [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/):

[image: BootStrap Modal look and feel]

**Modal window _MyConfirmModalWnd.cshtml**:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirmModalDialog" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalTitle">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Modal body              
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Yes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**View MyView.cshtml** (code in script section):

```
function askForConfirmation() {

    var success = function () {
                     // Do something on button 'Yes' clicked
                  };

    var cancel = function () {
                    // Do something on button 'No' clicked
                 };                 

    var title = "Caution!";
    var message = "You are about to invoice,\nDo you want to continue?";

    showConfirmation(title, message, success, cancel);
}

showConfirmation = function (title, message, success, cancel) {        
    var modal = $("#confirmModalDialog");
    modal.find(".modal-title").html(title).end()
         .find(".modal-body").html(message).end()
         .modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false })
         .on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
             modal.unbind();
         });
    if (success) {
        modal.one('click', '.modal-footer .btn-primary', success);
    }
    if (cancel) {
        modal.one('click', '.modal-header .close, .modal-footer .btn-default', cancel);
    }
};
```

Maybe... Do I have to import some specific javascript source files or css files in my modal view _MyConfirmModalWnd.cshtml?

**UPDATE**:
I have set margin and padding to 0 in the modal window _MyConfirmModalWnd.cshtml as below:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirmModalDialog" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true" style="margin:0;padding:0">
    <!-- Rest of the stuff -->
</div>
```

...and now modal window appearance seems ok except button 'x':

[image]

However modal window is not being vertically and horizontally centered on the screen despite of indicating it by using modal-dialog-centered. Why is it not being centered on the screen? am I missing something else?

**UPDATE 2**:
Finally I have made some adjustments to modal window:

- I have only set style="padding:0px" for outer div. Margin:0px is not necessary.
- I have set style="margin-top:-30px" for close button

Below the code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirmModalDialog" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true" style="padding:0px">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalTitle">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" style="margin-top:-30px">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Modal body              
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Yes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now modal window has below look and feel:

[image]

Things remaining to do:

- To center modal window vertically and horizontally on the screen.

**UPDATE 3**:

I have done a little more adjustments by overriding style. I have added below style attributes to the outer div:

- margin-left:0px
- left:42%

Additionally I have set a minimum width:

- min-width:15%

With above attributes overrided, modal window is centered horizontally.

To center vertically I have to set style attribute top:40% but once I add this attribute, modal window does not show. However if I open developer tools, with them opened, in debug mode, then modal window is shown. I do not understand why modal window behaves in this way when I add top:40% attribute.... Any ideas?

below the final code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirmModalDialog" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true" style="padding:0px;margin-left:0px;left:42%;min-width_15%"> <!-- NOTE:If I add top:40% then modal window is not shown,it is not being opened. It is only shown in debug mode when I make visible developer tools window -->
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalTitle">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" style="margin-top:-30px">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Modal body              
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Yes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you set the padding and margin of the body to 0? in your main css file

Comment: @FllnAngl I have not revised what you said yet. I am very new to this ASP.NET project. It was assigned to me recently. Anyway, Can I force and set padding and margin of the body to 0 in the modal view only without making changes to the main css file? 
I'm afraid to touch the main css file because I do not want it to affect the rest of the application.

Comment: I made a JSfiddle from your code to have a personal look. 

here only the x seems oddly placed https://jsfiddle.net/vzyuwadx/2/

Comment: do you show the modal using a `button` or `<input type=button>`, I used `<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmModalDialog">
  Launch demo modal
</button>` from the Modal bootstrap website

also assuming you have the required bootstrap libraries
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

`<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

in your App_Start -> BundleConfig.cs

Comment: but why would you need the X? since X == No;

Comment: @FllnAngl My view _ConfirmModalDialog.cshtml which contains the modal window is a partial view and it is embeded within another view using @Html.Partial("_ConfirmModalDialog.cshtml") so I am wondering if i need to enclose the code of modal windows between <html> and </html> tags and specify all the other stuff you indicated. Is it necessary? Also those js and css files, wil be applied to only partial view _ConfirmModalDialog.cshtml or it wil be applied to the entire app?

Comment: @FllnAngl the modal is shown through the javascript function askForConfirmation where I call the function showConfirmation by passing the required parameters. Then showConfirmation is in charge to show the modal.

Comment: @FllnAngl If I set js and css files in my modal window view _ConfirmModalDialog.cshtml, then they are applied to the entire view (cshtml) where partial view _ConfirmModalDialog.cshtml is embbeded and I do not want that. I only want to apply those css and js files to the partial view _ConfirmModalDialog.cshtml .

Comment: you should add those libraries to your `Layout.cshtml`

it will have effect over the whole application but you will need it if you want to use bootstrap classes.

if you have the code of modal windows in a `view.cshtml` which is being loaded inside the `layout.cshtml`, it should already automatically get encased with `<html>` tags since the `layout.cshtml` file contains the `<html>` and `<body>` tags.
and bootstrap requires the `jquery 1.11.1` library to function.

if you have newer versions of jquery, then you wont need the 1.11.1 version, as long as jquery works.

Comment: @FllnAngl I am using bootstrap v3.3.5 and jquery v1.7.1 and jquery v3.3.1 so I can understand those css and js you indicated are not necessary?

Comment: @FllnAngl Finally I have placed close button correctly by overriding style using style="margin-top:-30px". Now I am trying to center the modal window vertically and horizontally on the screen. Do you know how can I do it? See my last update.

Comment: oof sorry I forgot to respond. that should be achievable  https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp , https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_align_transform
 or 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KJFWsggjUcE

should probably be helpful

Comment: @FllnAngl Thanks for all your suggestions and recommendations. Finally I have centered modal window horizontally by overriding some style attributes. I was able to center it vertically as well by overriding top:40% attribute but when I set this attribute modal window only shows if I make visible developer tools in debug mode. If I do not make developer tools visible, then modal window is not shown. Any ideas why it is happening? See my last update: UPDATE 3.

Comment: that's strange.. try setting up multiple `console.log("some data")` in your code so you can track your javascript without debugging by opening the devconsole of the browser (F12)

maybe you'll notice, one of the `console.log()`s not showing up and you'll have an idea of what's missing.